# Count Distinct ID if it has more than 7 periods

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to counts students absent if they have skipped more than 8 bell periods on the same day. I was wondering if somebody could help me out here. I tried a distinct count with a counts of bell periods greater than 6 (that is the ballpark) but it is not working. I am providing a sample table below here.

[image]

Comment: Sample data should be posted as text in formatted tables. Schemas for tables should be included. The code you have tried should be included. A definition of "not working" should be provided, along with full quotes of any errors that encompasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count the items, but using ALLEXECPT, to count the items by only using the filter context of StudentID and Date

So for example based on your data, assuming that student 101 missed 9 bells then:

```
Measure = 
VAR _countofmisses = CALCULATE(COUNTAX(Table1, 1), ALLEXCEPT(Table1, Table1[Student ],Table1[Date]))
RETURN
IF(_countofmisses >=7, "Missed", "OK")
```

Which would give the following:
[image]

You can change the COUNTAX to a SUMX and still get the same result. All it is doing is counting/summing 1 for each row of the filter condition.

If I've read it wrong and student 101 has attended all 9 bells, just change the IF >= clause to the logic you need.